# R creates a list, instead of a data frame

Tags: r

I want to write a data frame to a file using the `write` function, however this doesnt work, because `data.frame()` creates it as a list.

Reproductive example:

```
data <- data.frame(cbind(1:2,3:4))
typeof(data)
data
#  X1 X2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
#> typeof(data)
#[1] "list"
```

Now when I want to write to file using

```
write(data,"data.txt")
```

I get an error saying

> Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
>     argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Which obviously happens because data is a list, but I dont understand why it is a list. Im running R 3.1.3

Comment: `?write.csv` may be what you want...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, your `data` *is* a `data.frame`:

```
class(data)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

The problem is that `write` does not cope well with data frames, but would work with matrices:

```
write(as.matrix(data), "test.txt")
```

If you want to write the data frame to a file use `write.table`:

```
write.table(data, "test.txt")
```

The error message comes from the underlying `cat` function and the fact that a `data.frame` is conceptually a list of vectors of same length.

Answer (score 1):

A data.frame is a list of vector structures of the same length. You can use `typeof (df)` to see that it shows the type of df (here an example data.frame) as "list".

You can use write.table to write a data.frame to a text file as shown below:

`write.table(df, "filename.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: So how is this solution differs from the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

How about `write.table(data,"data.txt")`?